# .replacewith every 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replace a div with another div every 30 seconds.

I have the below running however the div is not being replaced;

```
$( ".class1" ).setInterval(function() {
    $( this ).replaceWith('<div class="class2">54</div>');
} 3000);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is incredibly taxing on the application might I ask why?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gk69sde8/1/ - replacewith is not the right choice

Comment: If you just want to update the contents you can simply use `.text('new value');` instead.

Comment: Then you would need something like `.load()` or `.ajax()`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to change the text of the `span`?

```
 setInterval(changeText, 30000);
 function changeText(){
     if($(".class1").text() == "Hello World"){
          $(".class1").replaceWith("<div class='.class1'>My New Div</div>");
     }else{
         $(".class1").replaceWith("<div class='.class1'>Hello world</div>");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Are you answering or questioning???

Comment: @Jay you want to change the div text to hello world, and after 30 mins, you want to change it back to what?

Comment: @Jay I think my updated code may work?

Answer (score 1):

For toggling the text. You can use:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $('.class1').text($('.class1').text() == ".class1" ? "hello world" : ".class1")
},30000);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yuj56aze/)**

Comment: how will the two different div will look like?? can you share the html for second one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval()` this way:

```js
$(function() {
  var origText = $('.class1').text(); // cache it here
  
  setInterval(function() {
    var newTxt = $('.class1').text(); // now get the current text in the div
    
    var txt = newTxt != 'Hello World' ? 'Hello World' : origText; // on condition change the text
    $('.class1').text(txt); // change the text here now.
  
  }, 3 * 1000); // replace it as 30 * 1000 = 30 seconds


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='class1'>Class 1</div>
```